# Improving Mass Update Query Performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to run some remediation on my database which requires adding some new fields to a table and backfilling them based on specific criteria. There are a LOT of records and I'd prefer the backfill to run relatively fast, as my current query is taking forever to run.

I attempted updating via subqueries, but this doesn't seem to be very performant.

Query below is edited to show general process (so syntax might be a little off). Hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do./

I'd like to update every single record in the accounts table.

I'd like to do this by goin through each record and running a number of checks against the ID of that record prior to updating. For any records that don't match up in the join, I just want to set them to 0.

Doing this over the course of a few hundred thousand records seems to take forever. I'm sure there is a faster more efficient way to go about doing this. Using Postgres.

```
UPDATE

    accounts

SET

    account_age = a2.account_age,

FROM

    (

    with dataPoints as (

        select

            COALESCE(account__c.account_id as account_id,
account__c.account_age, 0) as account_age

        from account__c

        OUTER LEFT join points on points.account_id = account__c.id

        OUTER LEFT join goal__c on goal__c.id = scores.goal_id

    group by account_id, account__c.account_age

     )

       select

       account_id,

            max(dataPoints.account_age) as account_age,


        from scores

        join account on accounts.id = scores.account_id

        group by account_id

    ) as a2

WHERE accounts.id = a2.account_id;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Your CTE `dataPoints` is not used in the query at all. Can you simplify and/or explain your code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Postgres.

And apologies, the entire query is quite a bit longer, so I wanted to simply the one being provided to make my approach is bit more understandable. Query is updated to grab from dataPoints now.

Comment: Simple answer is to drop indexes on `accounts` table before doing the update, then recreate when complete.